# What does "It had better be good" mean in this context?

Tags: phrases

From the [Wellcome library collection](https://wellcomelibrary.org/collections/digital-collections/makers-of-modern-genetics/digitised-archives/fred-sanger/):

> When the Wellcome Trust Sanger Centre (now the Sanger Institute) was named after him in 1993, he told the Director, John Sulston: "It had better be good."

What do we make of what Sanger said? Does he mean that now that it bears *his* name, the institute ought to do good work? (That sounds unusual given that Sanger had an unassuming style and did stellar research all his professional life.)

> From New Oxford American English Dictionary:
>
> had better do something: would find it wiser to do something; ought to do something: you *had better* be careful.)

Comment: He undoubtedly felt that if the Sanger Centre had been deficient in some way it would have reflected poorly on his good name.

Comment: This is based on the question "_What_ had better be good?", which is about history and subjective application of a transparent expression.

Answer (score 1):

Likely he meant that now that the centre had his name on it he felt it must do a good job or he would feel bad, be embarrassed. This sounds like a show of modesty from someone who is being  honored with by having their name used on an institute.